# Why does my app crash when I tap on UITextField with iqkeyboardmanager?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, iqkeyboardmanager

I am using the [`iqkeyboardmanager`](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) to manage the keyboard in my app. When I tap on a UITextfield to edit it, the app get crashes with the following message:

```
-[UIWindow actualSceneBounds]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106c0d210
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This works fine in the simulator, but causes the app to crash with the error above on a device. The app works fine both in the simulator and on a device with `IQKeyboardManager` disabled.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint and post the code where the error appears?

Comment: Please check this link : https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/1391

Comment: I have used pod to install IQKeyboardManager swift version. And when I tap on any of the UITextfield, then the app is crashed with the error message as written above.

Comment: @VictorRay I have tried this solution but it does not worked for me.

Comment: Do u support iOS 10??

Comment: Please check their warning on their github repo. They said : If you're planning to build SDK/library/framework and want to handle UITextField/UITextView with IQKeyboardManager then you're totally going the wrong way.  I think you should not use this library. Instead create your own solution. I never used third party library for the simple solution.

Comment: i am looking for the solution. and i am not creating any library. I just want to handle the textfield so next and other features of IQKeyboard can be used.